# SQL Server get result from two rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I'm looking for a way to convert rows to columns in SQL Server. I am not sure how to do that. I need to compare only two years. For example I have

```
Year  Item     Qty
-------------------
2014  Shoes    500
2014  Ties     300
2014  Pants    200
2015  Shoes    600
2015  Ties     200
2015  Buttons  100
```

I want to get the data like following:

```
Item    Year1   Qty1    Year2   Qty2
------------------------------------
Shoes   2014    500     2015    600
Ties    2014    300     2015    200
Pants   2014    200     -       -
Buttons  -      -       2015    100
```

How the query should look like in order to get the result?

Comment: Use `PIVOT` or dynamic sql

Comment: Can you please write how to query here?

Comment: If you just need an adhoc query to get the total you could use a derived table to get the 2014 quantities, another derived table to get the 2015 quantities, then join those together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the code below:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [Year] SMALLINT
   ,[Item] VARCHAR(12)
   ,[Qty] SMALLINT
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([Year], [Item], [Qty])
VALUES (2014, 'Shoes', 500)
      ,(2014, 'Ties', 300)
      ,(2014, 'Pants', 200)
      ,(2015, 'Shoes', 600)
      ,(2015, 'Ties', 200)
      ,(2015, 'Buttons', 100);


SELECT [Item]
      ,IIF([2014] IS NOT NULL, 2014, NULL) AS [Year1]
      ,[2014] AS [Qty1]
      ,IIF([2015] IS NOT NULL, 2015, NULL) AS [Year2]
      ,[2015] AS [Qt2]
FROM @DataSource DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Qty]) FOR [Year] IN ([2014], [2015])
) PVT;
```

[image]

Anyway, you can use only the following code and the compare is seems easier, but I am not aware of your specific needs:

```
SELECT [Item]
      ,[2014]
      ,[2015]
FROM @DataSource DS
PIVOT
(
    MAX([Qty]) FOR [Year] IN ([2014], [2015])
) PVT;
```

[image]